# Using JQuery For Expand/Collapse in an ASP .NET Page with a Repeater Control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css, .net

My ASP .NET page contains a repeater control. Here is the HTML of interest. Note we have some custom controls in here, but I don't think that's important to my question.

```
<table style="border: 0px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
      <td style="width: 150px;">
     <b>Topic</b>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 250px; padding-right:10px;">
     <b>Score</b>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <asp:Repeater ID="_prvCtlRepeaterSurveyTopics" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 35%;">
         <div id="ClickToExplandDiv">
        <img id="_prvCtlImagePlusMinus" runat="server" alt="Expand/Collapse" src="" class="PlusMinus" />
        <customtagprefix:ctlEncodedLabel id="_prvCtlEncodedLabelTopicText" runat="server" CssClass="ECLink" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 30%;">
         <img id="_prvCtlImageTopic" runat="server" src="" alt="Score" />
      </td>
      <td style="width: 35%; white-space: nowrap;">
         <customtagprefix:ctlEncodedLabel id="_prvCtlLabelTopic" runat="server" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 3px 15px; width: 400px;" colspan="3">
        <div id="ExplandODiv">
        <customtagprefix:ctlRoundedGrayHeader id="_prvCtlRoundedGrayHeaderCF" runat="server" />
        <customtagprefix:ctlSummeryResultsList ID="_prvCtlSummaryResultsList" runat="server" />
        <customtagprefix:ctlRoundedGrayFooter id="_prvCtlRoundedGrayFooterCF" runat="server"/>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>                           
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

I want to be able to click on the DIV created by this code:

```
<div id="ClickToExplandDiv">
   <img id="_prvCtlImagePlusMinus" runat="server" alt="Expand/Collapse" src="" class="PlusMinus" />
   <customtagprefix:ctlEncodedLabel id="_prvCtlEncodedLabelTopicText" runat="server" CssClass="ECLink" />
</div>
```

and have the information displayed in this segment either expand or collapse:

```
  <td style="padding: 3px 15px; width: 400px;" colspan="3">
    <div id="ExplandODiv">
    <ayco:ctlRoundedGrayHeader id="_prvCtlRoundedGrayHeaderCF" runat="server" />
    <ayco:ctlSummeryResultsList ID="_prvCtlSummaryResultsList" runat="server" />
    <ayco:ctlRoundedGrayFooter id="_prvCtlRoundedGrayFooterCF" runat="server"/>
    </div>
  </td>
```

I am at a loss for the JQuery for this. Right now, I have the following which successfully hides all of the DIVs I want initially hidden and then opens just the first hidden DIV, no matter which of the expand-link DIV's I click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isInitialized = false;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        if (!isInitialized) {
            $('[id=ExplandODiv]').hide();
            isInitialized = true;
        }

        $('div[id=ClickToExplandDiv]').click(function() {
            $('#ExplandODiv:first-child').toggle();
        });
    });   
</script>
```

One way I can think to work around this would be to assign a "bogus class" to the elements as I run through them in the `ItemDatabound(...)` event. However, I am thinking that I should be able to use some sort of CSS selector that would select the appropriate DIV under the link I click. Maybe some derivitive of the "this" object, but I'm having a difficult time figuring this out.

I would appreciate any help you can provide on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your script area and it should work. And as the first answer pointed out, you should use classes instead of id. All you have to do is include Jquery and JqueryUI for the slideToggle animation.

```
var isInitialized = false;

$('.ClickToExpandDiv').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().next().find('.ExpandODiv').slideToggle();
    return false;
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    if (!isInitialized) {
        $('.ExpandODiv').hide();
        isInitialized = true;
    }

});
```

Feel free to check a test here http://jsfiddle.net/vecalciskay/54HxU/5/

hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I had to put the click event within the document ready event but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `id='ExplandODiv'` and `id='ClickToExplandDiv'` multiple times in your table. You should change these to classes.

```
$(function(){
    $(".ExplandODiv").hide();    
    $(".ClickToExplandDiv").click(function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").find(".ExplandODiv").toggle();
    });
});
```

Also, you're `if (!isInitialized)` check is unnecessary. If this solves some issue you were having you are probably doing something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You are correct. The isInitialized was not needed. I should have removed it. I changed the ID's to classes, but it is still not working. I will continue to look at it.

Comment: is that a zero in `ExplandODiv`? Does it increment each row?

Comment: No. It's an "oh". I named it expand-o because I'm super creative.